# Two notions of rectangle in TikZ?

Tags: latex, tikz

How do I integrate the notions of rectangle that appear in the sections "2.6 Rectangle Path Construction" and "71.2 Predefined Shapes" of the PGF/TikZ manual? In section 2.6 the manual explains that I can draw a rectangle by doing this:

> `\draw (1,2) rectangle (3,4);`

but I'm not being able to find the syntax for treating that rectangle as a particular case of the predefined shape "rectangle", and giving a name to it and accessing its reference points...

Comment: "treating that rectangle as a particular case of the predefined shape "rectangle"" -> it isn't a particular case of the node shape rectangle. If you want to give a name to it, you need to draw a node, not a path (`\draw` being a subcase of a path).